# Is there any similar JAVADOCS script/tool for Javascript files?

Tags: javascript, javadoc

Trying to find a way to automate the API from javascript comments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The JSDoc project is no longer active, you should give a look to [JsDoc Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/).

You might also want to check the following alternatives:

- [YUIDoc](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuidoc/)
- [PDoc](http://pdoc.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the multiple options.

Answer (score 5):

JSDoc http://jsdoc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: In that case, this should not be the selected answer. Perhaps @qodeninja could accept a different one?

Comment: Here's the current (as of May 2012) link to JSDoc's latest iteration, JSDoc 3: http://usejsdoc.org/ and https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc

Answer (score 5):

- [JSDoc Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/)
- [jGrouseDoc](http://code.google.com/p/jgrousedoc/)
- [YUI Doc](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuidoc/)
- [jsd100](http://code.google.com/p/jsd100/)
- [DocumentJS](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs/DocumentJS.html#&who=DocumentJS)

Answer (score 0):

I know its a lot late but since no one mentioned, I think [Docco](http://jashkenas.github.io/docco/) is a great tool. I use it for javascript but this tool can be used for other types of files too.