# What is the standard way of adding documentation to a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, documentation, documentation-generation

I'm looking at generating API docs for a JavaScript project. Does JavaScript have anything similar to Python's docstring?

```
function add(a, b) {
  /**
    Returns the sum of `a` and `b`.
  */
  return (a - 0) + (b - 0);
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800853/is-there-any-similar-javadocs-script-tool-for-javascript-files

Comment: Thanks @CMS - looks like I didn't search hard enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen **[JSDoc](http://jsdoc.sourceforge.net/)** (which has now been superceded by **[JSDoc toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/)**)?

Answer (score 3):

[JSDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc) is one way to do it.

```
/**
 * Adds two numbers.
 */
function add(a, b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

Comment: The `+` operator is not exclusively used for the arithmetic addition operation.

Answer (score 0):

When I needed it, JSDoc was the only available tool, and was pretty messy. We always got stack overflows because they used perl and regular expressions to parse the source. At first glance [JSDoc Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/) as mentioned look good, they're now using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

[PDoc](http://pdoc.org/) is an in-line documentation generator for the [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org) library, written in Ruby.