# How to run (Python-like) doctests in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, testing, doctest

Do any JavaScript test frameworks provide a rough equivalent to Python's doctest?

```
function add(a, b) {
  /**
  Returns the sum of `a` and `b`:

    > add(1, 3)
    4

  Add coerces types to numeric values where possible:

    > add('51' + 3)
    54
  */
  return (a - 0) + (b - 0);
}
```

Comment: Can you add more detail? At first glance this looked identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180224/what-is-the-standard-way-of-adding-documentation-to-a-javascript-function.

Comment: This question refers to doctests, that question refers to docstrings. They're fundamentally different, although they both occur within comments.

Comment: "How to run (Python) doctests in JavaScript?" makes me think you want to run Python code in JavaScript. I think you could remove the "(Python)" from your question title.

Comment: @Denilson Sá thanks for the comment. I changed the title in response to @John Kugelman's response. I wanted to clarify the distinctiveness of the question.

Comment: How about: How to run "Python-like" doctests in JavaScript?

Comment: Has anyone tried https://dev.to/supabase/use-comments-to-unit-test-your-code-4igk ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what I was smoking yesterday. Soory.

[doctestjs](http://ianb.github.com/doctestjs/) ([doctestjs on github](http://ianb.github.com/doctestjs/)) is the correct link and it seems to be under active development too.

Although it works a little different from the python doctest in that with doctestjs you declare the tests in a HTML file so they can be run.

But I guess it should be possible to declare the test inline in your code. And then do a preprocessing step in your build process to extract the tests and automagically create a test-html from them

e.g. when using ant I imagine an applying copy file, replaceregexp, concat.
e.g. copy the js file, replace everything which isn't a comment and all comments which don't look liks doctestjs tests. then concat htmlhead+tests+headfooter done.

Comment: Really? `JDocTest` is for Java, `jsdoc-toolkit` doesn't appear to have any integrated testing facilities http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/w/list?can=2&q=test.

Comment: it seems to be abandoned now, do you know of any replacement?

Answer (score 12):

I can't get the point of Ian Bicking's package, doctestjs. He just provides us a different way of writing normal external tests, not real doctests.

I use a lot python doctests, they are quite important for me, I don't know what doctestjs could be useful for, but I found some true doctests implemented with this project: https://github.com/davidchambers/doctest .

Even if that is not the most trendy doctest project for javascript, I strongly prefer it.

---

**Update:** after more that one year since this answer, i had the opportunity to contribute to the project from David Chambers, it is really well written. I also used it at work in a complex application using [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), and for this we added support for AMD modules. I think he added support for Common JS modules as well. Thus i can only confirm my opinion.

Comment: project from David Chambers = https://github.com/davidchambers/doctest